# Reading in a line from file or stdin dynamically

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic, memory-leaks, malloc

I am posed with a situation where my function does exactly what I want except handle higher amounts of input.

I initially thought to process each character one by one but was running into problems doing this. So `fscanf` not only does what I want it to do but it is essential in reading in only one line. I noticed, I cannot reallocate space for bigger array this way though. I have tried using format specifiers i.e. `%*s` to include a specific amount of buffer space before hand but this still does not work.

I have noticed also, I would have no way of knowing the size of the string I am reading in.

Here is my attempt and thoughts:

```
#define LINE_MAX 1000

char* getline(FILE* inputStream)
{
    int capacity = LINE_MAX;
    char* line = malloc(capacity * sizeof(char));
    int ch;

    /* if (sizeof(capacity) == sizeof(line)) { // Not a valid comparison? Too late?
        capacity *= 2;
        line = realloc(line, capacity * sizeof(line));
    } */

    if (fscanf(stream, "%[^\n]s", line) == 1) {
        ch = fgetc(inputStream);
        if (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
            fscanf(inputStream, "%*[^\n]");
            fscanf(inputStream, "%*c");
        }
        free(line);
        return line;
    }
    free(line);
    return NULL;
}
```

I am new to memory allocation in general but I feel as though I had a good idea of what to do here. Turns out I was wrong.

Comment: `free(line);
        return line;` that _is_ undefined behaviour. Don't free your buffer. Leave it to the caller when it's not used anymore.

Comment: sizeof doesn't do what you think it does. (And I have no idea what you think sizeof(capacity)   does.)

Comment: If I do not return line, then I will not get my line.

Comment: I know @rici, It is an idea of what I am trying to do. If buffer reaches capacity, double buffer space.

Comment: So keep track of how much you have used. Posix provides [`getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) and there are [sample implementations](https://gist.github.com/ingramj/1105106) you can study.

Comment: @rici this has a different function definition than what I am going for

Comment: You don't document your requirements so I'll take your word for it. However, it seemed likely that the example code, which both reads dara and reallocates a buffer, would have something of interest. If not, I apologise for the distraction.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to read a line and store it in a Character array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    signed char *str;
    int c;
    int i;
    int size = 10;
    str = malloc(size*sizeof(char));
    for(i=0;(c=getchar()) !='\n' && c != EOF;++i){
        if( i == size){
            size = 2*size;
            str = realloc(str, size*sizeof(char));
            if(str == NULL){
                printf("Error Unable to Grow String! :(");
                exit(-1);
            }
        } 
        str[i] = c;
    }
    if(i == size){
        str = realloc(str, (size+1)*sizeof(char));
        if(str == NULL){
            printf("Error Unable to Grow String! :(");
            exit(-1);
        }

    }
    str[i] = '\0';
    printf("My String : %s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

The array is resized to twice it's original size if current array can't hold the characters read from input.

Comment: My problem is, I use a similar approach except I use fgetc to pull from file stream. If I call my program as ./program < input.txt, and it reads until EOF, I am stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: when you do "./program < input.txt" you 're changing the input stream, the above code should be fine,

Comment: In order to compare with `EOF` it is necessary to use `int` for `c`, not `char`. In addition, this program may cause buffer overrun.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY getchar() returns an int so c here holds the int/ASCII value of any character read why won't it work for EOF? Also regarding buffer overrun can you please explain.

Comment: 1) `char` is `signed char` or `unsigned char`. Since `EOF` is usually implemented with negative numbers(E.g.`-1`), it does not match when implemented with `unsigned char`.

Comment: thanks for replying when we say char its signed by default right? So it's good coding practice to mention explicitly whether it's signed or unsigned right. Also regarding buffer overrun I don't understand can you please explain.

Comment: 2) E.g Since the `if( i == size){` is not established at the input of the ninth letter, it is not expanded. At the end of this loop `i` is incremented to `10`. If a newline is entered at the beginning of the next loop, it exits the loop.  And `str[i] = '\0';` is executed, but since the `i` is `10`(So `str[10] = '\0';`), it is beyond the reserved buffer.

Comment: _we say char its signed by default right?_ No, it is implementation dependent. It is not necessarily signed.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks, I still don't get why I didn't get a segfault or runtime error when I gave input string as helloworld :P thanks for the help I will update the code.

Comment: 1-2) `getchar()` returns an `int`. The breakdown is `0`-`255`(a character) and `-1`(`EOF`). When `signed char` is used as a receiver, This time, since it is the same as 255(`'\xFF'` and `-1`(`EOF`)), it malfunctions. In other word, it is determined that the character `'\xFF'`(which may not be used much  but it is not `EOF`) is `EOF`. Therefore, you should use `int` as mentioned at the beginning.

Comment: store the int in char array?

Comment: After the check of `EOF` is done, it is within the range that can be expressed with `char`, so there is no problem.

Comment: So use signed or unsigned char in this situation? I saw a few answers which say if you're reading from a jpeg or some other file tile and doing "raw" reads then using unsigned is correct as we are storing the binary data .In this case using unsigned wrong as we are storing an int value directly. BTW really appreciate you spending time helping me on this thanks a ton! :)

Comment: _So use signed or unsigned char in this situation?_ In the case where comparison with `EOF` is necessary, the receiver type of `getchar`(`fgetc` and `getc`)  needs to be `int` as already explained. If you don't need to compare with `EOF`, you don't necessarily need to use `int`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXYThanks a lot. :)